# Why the subtracting the time.time() value before and after a pool.map doesn't give the expected time?

Tags: python, time, multiprocessing, python-3.7, pool

I'm still trying to learn about doing parallel computation via Python (I have some other questions posted here in the same topic). Here I tried to use multiprocessing, pool, imap_unordered in two ways and measuring the time it takes to process the computations. I get a non-expected value for the time in both cases.

The example is just summing numbers from 1 to n. The time for doing this without parallel computations for one choice of n, n=10000000 is 0.8 second. Then by multiprocessing and 8 cpu's, for 8 choices of n (n=10000000, ..., 10000007) is almost the same (the amount of time I wait to see the result is the same almost 0.8 second). But when I want the time of this computation to be reported by the time.time() trick, I get 0.0 or 0.02 seconds!!!! The codes I tried are in below. Can someone guide me what is wrong in my codes? One more thing, where should I use `if __name__ == '__main__':` exactly and how many times?

```
import time
def sumo(n):
    sumor=0
    for i in range(n):
        sumor+=i
    return(sumor)
x0=10000000
st=time.time()
x=sumo(x0)
st=time.time()-st
print(x,st)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing
    pool=multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    nvec=[]
    for i in range(8):
        nvec.append(x0+i)
    st=time.time()
    sp=pool.imap_unordered(sumo,nvec)
    st=time.time()-st
    for i in sp:
        print(i)
    print(st)
```

Output after running the code;

```
49999995000000 0.8040459156036377
49999995000000
50000005000000
50000015000001
50000035000006
50000045000010
50000065000021
50000055000015
50000025000003
0.0
```

The second try;

```
import time
def sumo(n):
    sumor=0
    for i in range(n):
        sumor+=i
    return(sumor)
x0=10000000
st=time.time()
x=sumo(x0)
st=time.time()-st
print(x,st)
import multiprocessing
def sumoparallel(nvec):
    pool=multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    return(pool.imap_unordered(sumo,nvec))
nvec=[]
for i in range(8):
    nvec.append(x0+i)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    st=time.time()
    sp=sumoparallel(nvec)
    st=time.time()-st
    sq=[]
    for i in sp:
        sq.append(i)
    print(sq,st)
```

Output after running the code;

```
49999995000000 0.8280472755432129
[49999995000000, 50000015000001, 50000045000010, 50000055000015, 50000035000006, 50000005000000, 50000025000003, 50000065000021] 0.02500128746032715
```

Comment: This is not a computation that can be easily made parallel in python; you need to keep track of the sum on each loop across processes. You should first be using the build in `sum()` rather than a python loop, or numpy arrays for speed. `multiprocessing` gives the impression that it will speed up computations but really it comes with a lot of overhead and the loop should have independent calculations for real benefit

Comment: @roganjosh May you please explain a bit more? To me what I'm doing seems 8 independent sums, so theoretically it should be possible to do them in parallel as I can do it in Maple for example.

Comment: Sure, you're doing 8 independent sums. Why should any of them run faster than 1 sum on 1 core? They aren't _collaboratively_ generating a single sum, they're all doing the same work, independently

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, that's exactly what I wanted to do. And I didn't want it to be faster than one sum on one core. The goal was doing 8 instances of an action with the time required for only one instance.

Comment: Then use individual `Process`es and not `map`.

Comment: @roganjosh can you refer to a link or explain how to do it? And I should emphasize again that the goal is not to do 8 instances of an action one after the other one so it takes 8 times of doing one action on one core. Plus that the input of the 8 actions can be different.

Comment: `.imap_unordered()` *doesn't wait for results* - it immediately returns an iterator that will yield the next result that arrives.  If you want something you can time, use `.map()` instead.

Comment: @jasonharper replacing `.imap_unordered()` with `.map()` in both codes gave me 3.3 seconds which sounds like four tasks on one core. Is something wrong in my use of `multiprocessing` or `time.time()` or multiprocessing is not really doing a parallel computation that I expected?

Comment: The examples of my suggestion are in the documentation

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you. If you put your comment as an answer, I will upvote it. I varied the number of workers in the pool from 1 to 8 for these 8 tasks and I got the following time measured; `7.07`, `4.01`, `3.29`, `2.87`, `2.92`, `3.17`, `3.61`, `3.36`. So it is really parallel and I do remember reading that efficiency of multiprocessing has such a behavior.